# tiny question about jquery's live()

Tags: live, jquery

How would I change the html of a tag like so:

> `$('#someId').html('<p>foo bar</p>');`

while using the live() or delegate() function? Just for clarification I don't want this to happen on hover or focus or click... I just want jquery to immediately change the html inside of a certain tag.

Basically, I'm trying to change the logo in the Mojomotor's little dropdown panel and I don't want to change the logo every time I upgrade to a new version.

Any suggestions?

Comment: so when exactly do you want to change the logo? why do you need live or delegate if it's not happening on some event.

Comment: I don't know... but trying to change it on doc ready wasn't working so I thought I might have to use live or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) don't work like this, what you're after is still done through [the `.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) or simply in the `document.ready` if it's present on page load, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#someId').html('<p>foo bar</p>');
});
```

Or with [`.livequery()`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) if it's replaced dynamically in the page:

```
$('#someId').livequery(function() {
  $(this).html('<p>foo bar</p>');
});
```

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) work off of event bubbling...an element just appearing doesn't do this whereas a `click` or `change`, etc would.

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing it on document ready with no results so I'll try the livequery plugin you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it when the DOM loads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#someId').html('<p>foo bar</p>'); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure you have included the jquery library and be sure to put the ready function between script tags. Also post the HTML of #someId and we might be able to see why.